# sudo: unable to excute ./blah.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, sh

I got this error

```
sudo: unable to excute ./blah.sh: No such file or directory
```

my code is every simple

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "blah"
```

And I'm sure that I've changed the permission to "rwx". When I try sudo bash blah.sh, I will get the output. But I still cant execute the file. And I'm in debian OS.
Anyone knows why?

Comment: What command are you executing? It looks like you are not in the correct directory.

Comment: `sudo ./blah.sh` is the command i ran. i'm in the right directory i think, because when i ran the other .sh in the same dir, they worked.

Comment: What if you do `sudo /full/path/of/blah.sh` ?

Comment: `rwx` is an incomplete permission string; there are separate permissions for owner, user, and other. What is the output of `ls -l blah.sh`?

Comment: @fedorqui I just tried, but it didnt work. :(

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your advice. The full permission is `-rw-rwxrwx`

Comment: See rob's answer. You've given everyone *except* the owner permission to execute the file.

Answer (score 1):

make it executable

```
sudo chmod a+x ./blah.sh
```

that sets the executable bit for all users just

```
+x
```

for your single user

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but It still remained the same error code. And the permissions are changed to `-rwxrwxrwx` already.

Answer (score 0):

Check in /etc/sudoers if your username is allowed to sudo.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've checked. The username is allowed to sudo.

Comment: The bash would have said that if he wasn't in the sudoers list.

Comment: Can you paste the output of ls -l blah.sh ?